# Edit the fields of migrations in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Is advisable to do a rake db:rollback when I am wrong in a field of the database; then a rake db:migrate to create the correct structure of the database?

Comment: Yes, it is both advisable and correct. If you happen to have any data in the affected table that you do not wish to lose, you will need to do a backup and restore as well.

Comment: this is situation dependent. If you have data in the field then it may be better to create a new migration which creates the new field migrates the data into this field and then drops the old one. If you just don't like the name you can create a migration that renames the field. It all depends on the state of the project and the data that may exist. I generally always create a new migration to handle these situations as it involves the least number of hoops and the least possibility of data destruction

Comment: db:rollback is okay to do when you're in development environment. However as soon as you publish your code, you should never change old migrations(Reasons being, 1. data in the affected schema, 2. All who have pulled your code and ran migration will have to rollback)

Answer (score 2):

In development environment that might be an option.

But as soon as you pushed the migration to a remote repository and another developer ran that migration against his database or the migration ran on staging or production, you should not change the migration anymore.

Instead, add just new migration in such cases.